# Code comment visible on company pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

It seems that there is a code comment rendered at the end of all company pages, under their jobs section. It says:

> // This view is proxied, which strips out the layout, so we need to "re-include" required files

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/wikimedia-foundation-inc

I can reproduce this on other company pages as well.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

There's a lot of ways to write comments in code, but I happened to choose the wrong one. Should be fixed now - thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Might be easier to open source SO if you want us to CR your code ;-)

Fixed indeed. Thanks!

Comment: In my ide i use a comment shortcut which uses correct commenting syntax regardless of the file type.